# Component in a loop does not show the last component in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components, handlebars.js

I'm a beginner to ember js. Here I'm looping a component called colored-box in the 'reading.hbs' file. This loop of components shows all the other elements with relevant properties. But the last element is not showing. In the component js file, I have used observes method with init. I'm downloading a pdf which is generated using the html rendered with this code with pdfReadctor. I got this issue in the downloaded pdf. I have attached the image of the place where I have the issue. I can't figure out what the reason is. Can anyone please help me to figure out the problem? Below I have attached the code.

Figure 1.) reading.hbs
[image]

Figure 2.) colored-box.hbs - component file
[image]

Figure 3.) colored-box.js
[image]

[image]

Comment: The syntax looks fairly old. A ember-twiddle.com reproduction would be helpful to solve the issue.

Comment: debug with log helper. check size and color value argument pass correctly. then inspect in the browser.

Comment: I personally have a lot of trouble reading code in images like this, putting the code directly in the question inside of code blocks would help me answer this question.

Comment: @Rabbihasan Thank you so much for replying. But here I inspected in the browser. It rendered the Html correctly. But when downloading, the problem persists. size and color value argument shows correct values when debugging and printing.